# Using GNUMP how to find logarithm of base10

Tags: c++, double, gmp, bignum

I am facing a problem in C++. i need a double which is more precise than standard c++ double.
(C++ long double is even not enough) so.. i found GNUMP that does satisfy me.. but..

How do i find the logarithm of base 10 of a given number..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The short answer is that the [GNU MP Library](http://gmplib.org/) is not the complete solution; it only provides integer and rational functions.  However, the [MPFR](http://www.mpfr.org/) library is built on top of and used/linked with the GNUMP library and it provides the transcendental functions you need.

Answer (score 0):

Have you used this equation: lg(a) = ln(a)/ln(10); with this you can find the logarithm of base 10 of a given number.